# swap image when hovering over its container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I've hit a brick wall trying to swap an image when hovering over its containing div.

i can do it with css, but i have 6 div's with 6 images contained in them. if i did it in css, i would need 6 sets of hover events to change the background image. i want to do this with the most simple code possible.

at the moment the images are not set as a background image but as an `<img src>`

all hover images use the same name but with'over' added into the file name.

ie. shop.png shopover.png is their away to append the img src file name to add the 'over' part when hovering over its container div?

html :

```
<div class="row">

         <a href="index.php?page=exhibitorlist&id=1"> <div class="c2 center"><img src="images/eliquid.png"><h2 class="center">Juice Brands</h2></div></a>
           <a href="index.php?page=exhibitorlist&id=2"> <div class="c2 center"><img src="images/mod.png"><h2 class="center">Hardware</h2></div></a>              
          <a href="index.php?page=exhibitorlist&id=3"><div class="c2 center"><img src="images/dist.png"><h2 class="center">Distributors</h2></div></a>
          <a href="index.php?page=exhibitorlist&id=4"><div class="c2 center on"><img src="images/shop.png"/><h2 class="center">Retailers</h2></div></a>              
          <a href="index.php?page=exhibitorlist&id=5"><div class="c2 center"><img src="images/robot.png"><h2 class="center">Machinary / Packaging</h2></div></a>
          <a href="index.php?page=exhibitorlist&id=6"><div class="c2 center"><img src="images/other.png"><h2 class="center">Other</h2></div></a>       
</div>
```

css :

```
#exhibitorcontainer {
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
background:url(../images/bg2.png) repeat;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#exhibitorcontainer .c2 {
margin: 0 5px;
width: 15.8%;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#exhibitorcontainer h2 {
font-size:16px;
color: #1b9bff;
}
#exhibitorcontainer .c2:hover h2 {
color:#666;
}
```

at the moment i switch the H2 from blue to grey, i want to do the same for the image. any ideas on the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpliest way is to use two images:

```
<div class="c2 center">
  <img src="images/dist.png" class="normal-image">
  <img src="images/dist-over.png" class="hover-image">
  <h2 class="center">Distributors</h2>
</div>
```

Then use the CSS:

```
.hover-image, .c2:hover .normal-image {
  display: none;
}

.c2:hover .hover-image {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can change simply, by using javascript as given below:

Image code of html

```html
<img src="images/click.png" onmouseover="ic()" id="myImage"/>
```

Image change by javascript

```js
function ic(){
  document.getElementById('myImage').src='images/yes.png';
}
```

Now when mouseover on your image then javascript call this function and set your image there, if you want that when mouseover not on image, then image return on previous so use same script for viceversa.